# why no jsp entry in web.xml?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, deployment-descriptor

When we create a servlet we make entry in deployment descriptor i.e. web.xml but when we create a jsp we don't make entry in web.xml? Is it due to there is servlet container for serving servlets and jsp container for serving jsps?

Comment: Good question mate.. I'm also curious about it.

Comment: I think this is only due to the fact that a jsp declare his path by his filename. A servlet path was declared in web.xml, now we can declare it with anotations since Servlet 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, JSP container takes care of JSP page requests.  Servlet
container finds the servlet in container which matches the URL in the
request.

For more detailed info on how JSP container handles the JSP request , you can refer to posts below :

Hope this helps.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/364444/Servlets/java/JSP-container

Answer (score 0):

It is not true.. that fact is that they are also get noticed... but we do not have do that.. as web server (Jsp Container) internally compiles Jsp to servlets it makes an entry for each jsp on its first request itself in its inner configuration file and uses that path for all requests. When a request is made to the jsp page the server checks for the current page in its config file and provides the response.

If we wish to change the url of our jsp page, we ourself can make some entries in the web.xml as same as of servlets

e.g. IN tomcat, JSPs get configured in the conf/web.xml file.

That's it.